# Power BI Change SLICER background colour when selected

Tags: powerbi, dax, power-bi-report-server

I Have a slicer which display YES, NO and select all
[image]

what  want to achieve is to change the background colour to yellow base on the one I select.
For example if I select "Yes"
I want to see
[image]

if I select "No" then

[image]

if I select "Select all" then

[image]

Note I can only select one filter at a time
any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Bookmark Navigator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/button-navigators?tabs=powerbi-desktop#bookmark-navigator) or 3 separate buttons linked to bookmarks instead of a single slicer.